# Programmatically login User on Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

Version: Symfony2.3

There is many link that shows how to login programmatically on Symfony or Changing user Roles dynamically on login. I referred some sites and got the code working.

Below the Process,

- User login with username and password
- User will be redirected to Group list page
- User will select one group
- We will change the Role mapped with the selected Group dynamically and redirect user

Every thing works fine.

But problem is:
I am using below code to get user id in all Pages, is stop working after changing "Token"

```
$id = $this->getUser()->getId();
```

I have a function with dynamically change Current User role based on different Groups

```
// Save the original token in the session 
$originalToken = $this->get("security.context")->getToken();
$this->getRequest()->getSession()->set('original.security.token', $originalToken);

// Create my new custom token (loading the roles of the user)
$token = new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken($this->getUser()->getUsername(), null, "secured_area", array($dynamic_rolename));

// Update the security context with the new token
$this->get("security.context")->setToken($token);
$this->get('session')->set('security_secured_area',serialize($token));
```

The line `$this->getUser()->getId()` not working after the above function executed.

```
Error: FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object
```

Security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    Core\Bundle\Entity\login:
        algorithm:        sha1
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations:       1

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    administrators:
        entity: 
            class: Core\Bundle\Entity\login
            property: userName

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        security: false
        anonymous:  ~
        context: administration

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        context: administration
        form_login:
            check_path: _security_check
            login_path: /login
            default_target_path: /admin/setfacility
        logout:
            path:   _demo_logout
            target: _demo
        #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"
```

Why the getUser() object not been set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Create my new custom token (loading the roles of the user)
$token = new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken($this->getUser()->getUsername(), null, "secured_area", array($dynamic_rolename));
```

In the above section you are using UsernamePasswordToken for the token creation.This accepts 4 parameters. The first parameter can be :

The username (like a nickname, email address, etc.), or a UserInterface instance or an object implementing a __toString method.

You are just passing the username . Pass the user entity instead so that you can have $this->getUser()->getId() working.

Comment: Thanks, It solved my problem, nearly a day searching :)

Answer (score 1):

You set a value into a session but didn't save it. So you should save it:

```
$this->get('session')->set('security_secured_area',serialize($token));
$this->get('session')->save(); // add this line
```

Answer (score 0):

Check first do you have a `User` object:

```
if ($this->getUser()) {
    $id = $this->getUser()->getId();
}
```

in your case the `User` object is `NULL`, so you try to call `getId()` method from `NULL` not from `User` object, that throw this error message.